# Efficient way to search this json array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My programmer is having trouble getting the `location` data (latitude and longitude) from this json array. What would a `foreach` loop be which would find the lat/long of `location:` and echo them? Thanks

`$jsonArray = json_decode($jsondata, true);`

```
$jsondata =  {
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "2340",
                   "short_name" : "2340",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "New South Wales",
                   "short_name" : "NSW",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Australia",
                   "short_name" : "AU",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "New South Wales 2340, Australia",
             "geometry" : {
                "bounds" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : -30.79897870,
                      "lng" : 151.394080
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : -31.661670,
                      "lng" : 150.334880
                   }
                },
                "location" : {
                   "lat" : -31.28146910,
                   "lng" : 151.04713550
                },
                "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : -30.79897870,
                      "lng" : 151.394080
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : -31.661670,
                      "lng" : 150.334880
                   }
                }
             },
             "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a loop? You can just access it directly with:

```
echo $jsonArray['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
```

With multiple results, it would be

```
foreach( $jsonArray['results'] as $row) { 
    $lat = $row['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $long = $row['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    echo $lat . ' ' . $long . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'm not the programmer so figured a loop would be needed to search the entire array.

Comment: Not a problem! You will need a loop if more than one results are returned. I updated my answer as I forgot `list()` can't be used on an associative array.

Comment: hmm..i'm confused. Why after 'results' its zero in the path and not like that: $jsonArray['results']['geometry']['location']['lat']  ?

results is an array so if you say ['results'][0] you take the first element which is "address_components".

Your code works but i just cant understand the zero :)

Comment: Just do a `var_dump()` of `$jsonArray['results']`, you should see why.